# How to check if multidimensional array contains same value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. I need to check if any value in this array has contain same value. If, then execute. What is the better way to check this, or the simplest way TIA

```
$array[] = array(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
$array[] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$array[] = array(2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14);

Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 15
        [3] => 20
        [4] => 25
        [5] => 30
   )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 6
    ) 

 [2] => Array
     (
       [0] => 2
       [1] => 6
       [2] => 8
       [3] => 10
       [4] => 12
       [5] => 14
    )
)
```

Comment: "if any of the array have has contain same" um what?

Comment: that edit really did not help

Comment: @nogad Haha, sorry not english

Comment: You could add an example of a case that fullfills your constraints, and a case that does not. Maybe you're trying to find if a value is contained in two different arrays ? Maybe something else.

Comment: haha, well can't help if you can't write a coherent English question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for a way of finding values that appears in more than one of the inner arrays..? Here are two solutions for that, using some built-in PHP array methods.

**Setup**

- Flatten `$array` (initial step for both methods) using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) on itself

Code:

```
$array[] = array(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
$array[] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$array[] = array(2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 5);

// 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 5
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

**Method A**

1. Get an array of [unique values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in `$array` (duplicates removed)
2. Get what was removed (= the duplicates) by [comparing that array to the original `$array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)
3. Make sure values [appear only once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in the final array

Code:

```
$duplicates =
    array_unique(
        array_diff_key(
            $array,
            array_unique($array)
        )
    );

// $duplicates = 5, 2, 6, 10
```

**Method B**

1. Get a list of [how many times each value appears](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) in `$array`
2. [Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) that list keeping only values that appears more than once (= duplicates)
3. [Get the keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) of that list (the actual `$array` values)

Code:

```
$duplicates =
    array_keys(
        array_filter(
            array_count_values($array),
            function ($count) {
                return $count > 1;
            }
        )
    );

// $duplicates = 5, 10, 2, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the array and subarray filling $isRepeated with values and frequencies of appearance. When $isRepeated[certain_value] exists means this value was found before:

```
$array[] = array(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
$array[] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$array[] = array(2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14);

$isRepeated = array();
foreach($array as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $item) {
        if (!isset($isRepeated[$item])) {
            $isRepeated[$item] = 0;
        } else {
            $isRepeated[$item]++;
            echo "\n<br>Item $item is repeated";
        } 
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/9yObII

Output:

```
Item 5 is repeated
Item 2 is repeated
Item 6 is repeated
Item 10 is repeated
```

Comment: You should _explain_ your solution. Don't just dump code.