# Check if multidimensional array values are the same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1
        [order_id] => 1
        [is_accepted] => 0
        [is_canceled] => 0
        [is_completed] => 0
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1
        [order_id] => 1
        [is_accepted] => 0
        [is_canceled] => 0
        [is_completed] => 0
    )

)
```

I want check if both [is_canceled] values are 1 it return true.
If one of [is_canceled] value is 1 it return false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604340/how-to-check-if-multidimensional-array-contains-same-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if multidimensional array contains same value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604340/how-to-check-if-multidimensional-array-contains-same-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple `foreach` loop to iterate over the array of objects, to check each object's `is_canceled` field.

```
function containsNoCancelledOrders($orders) {
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if ($order["is_canceled"]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$orders = [
    [
        "entity_id" => 1,
        "order_id" => 1,
        "is_accepted" => 0,
        "is_canceled" => 0,
        "is_completed" => 0,
    ],
    [
        "entity_id" => 1,
        "order_id" => 1,
        "is_accepted" => 0,
        "is_canceled" => 0,
        "is_completed" => 0,
    ],
];

var_dump($orders);
echo containsNoCancelledOrders($orders) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: It return true if 1 of 2 _is_canceled_ value is 1.
I want it return true if all _is_canceled_ values are 1

Comment: @SeventhSt Then you should put in more effort into asking a better question. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet,

```
var_dump(!in_array(0,array_column($orders,'is_canceled')));
```

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) -> Return the values from a single column in the input array

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) ->  Checks if a value exists in an array

Give it a try, this should work.

Comment: i've never heard of `array_column()` before now but wow that is awesome.

Comment: Oh thanks, it will be better to use, in op's kinda of case.

Comment: Updated comment ! Happens sometimes ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function check($array) 
{
    if ($array[0]['is_cancelled'] == 0 && $array[1]['is_cancelled'] == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$check = check($array);
var_dump($check);
```